# Failure anomalies smart alert missing from Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

As the title suggests, I just created a new application insights instance and there is a Failure Anomalies alert (generated by smart detections) which is awesome.

[image]

However it seems to be missing from some our existing App Insights instances missing alert

[image]

Any info on how to restore this alert and how to change the severity of some of the existing alerts would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

This means there was an issue during provisioning of this feature for your Application Insights resource. If that is still the case, you will need to contact Azure Support and your AI resource would get provisioned.